# How to extract country borders as vector data from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, vector, download, borders

I want to download country borders as vector data from OpenStreetMap. The best would be in a common vector geodata format like GeoJSON that can be used e.g. in QGIS. I there a simple way to do this?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379763/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401024/88814

Comment: Thank you! I know that the answer can be found at GIS SE already, but it seems that no one has asked explicitly how to download country vector data from OSM - and a [separate Q&A seemed valuable due to this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/473423/52808).

Comment: I'll just add a note to download OSM data in QGIS for set areas use the OSM Downloader Plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download country borders from OpenStreetMap, you can use [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). I used the following expression:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
relation[boundary=administrative][admin_level=2]["name:en"=Switzerland];
out geom;
```

[Here's a direct link to the query](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1FeU) (example country: Switzerland).

Replace the value after `"name:en"=` with the English name of your country or use `name=` to query it using the official (short) country name. Don't forget to insert quotes if the name contains spaces or special characters.

You can get the data as GeoJSON via *Export > GeoJSON Download*. When you load the layer into QGIS, only load the polygons.

**A note on country borders including territorial waters:** If your country includes a coastline to international waters (maritime borders), the national territory in OSM includes the territorial waters (usually 12 nautical miles from the low-tide coastline). To query only the landmass you might need a workaround when using OSM data. In some countries, downloading all level 4 administrative areas might work. Here's an example for Italy:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Italy}};
relation[admin_level=4][boundary=administrative]["ISO3166-2"~"IT-"](area);
out geom;
```

[Here's a direct link to the query](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1FeW)

`"ISO3166-2"` is used here because without a unique country identifier parts of neighboring countries might be included due to inaccuracies.

Dissolve the layer to one Polygon/MultiPolygon in QGIS to reduce data volume.

However, this does not work for all countries either because no admin level exists that covers only the landmass or because level 4 administrative units also include territorial waters (e.g. Germany).

Comment: This was an excellent answer, I imported a .GeoJSON into QGIS and exported it out of QGIS as a .SHP

Comment: How would I do this for all the smaller admin levels (districts) in Malawi or to get Malawi with all its districts in one geojson? I tried changing the "admin_level=" to a different value but that doesn't seem to have worked. I know OSM has all the sub levels because I can see them on the OSM world basemap in QGIS

Comment: You can get all districts like this:
`[out:json][timeout:25];
relation[admin_level=4][boundary=administrative]["ISO3166-2"~"MW-"];
out geom;`
Lower levels (e.g. `admin_level=8` for municipal level) don't seem to exist for Malawi.